# return statement in .then() part of promise returning undesired value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, es6-promise

```
module.exports.getTopMeal = function () {
    mealKitModel.find({ "top_meal": true })
        .then((kits) => {
            return kits;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error finding top mealkit");
        })
}
```

Here, I am trying to find objects which have the top_meal attribute true from the mongoDB. When I put "console.log(kits)" statement in.then(kits) part, it gives me desired output. But when I import this function in another javascript file, the return value of this function shows undefine. I am returning kits in .then() part so that first execution of find promise completes then it returns kits variable.

Please, anyone, show me where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the promise.

```
module.exports.getTopMeal = function () {
    return mealKitModel.find({ "top_meal": true })
        .then((kits) => {
            return kits;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error finding top mealkit");
        })
}
```

Now you can do

```
getTopMeal().then(topMeal => {
  console.log(topMeal)
})
```

In addition. Since the find method return kits, you don't need to explicitely return it, so the function becomes:

```
module.exports.getTopMeal = function () {
    return mealKitModel.find({ "top_meal": true })
}
```

Note that I also removed the catch function from mealKitModel.find since generally you don't want to catch every function and log it out, but instead have a single error handler at the end. It's better practice just to return the promise and handle it later.

Basically: If you catch in mealKitModel.find you can't catch the error from getTopMeal.

But now, with the refactor where you simply return the promise you can now do:

```
getTopMeal().then(topMeal => {
  console.log(topMeal)
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log('now we can catch the error')
  console.log(e)    
})
```

Comment: There are two other things to fix here.  The `.then(kits => return kits)` is entirely unnecessary since that's already the resolved value of the promise.  And, the `.catch()` is "eating" the error and not letting it propagate back to the caller.  If you're going to log the error internally, then you have to rethrow it so the caller will see the rejection.

Comment: Yeah, I added that. Just hadn't saved the changes before your comment :)

Comment: I don't know whether you did it on purpose or not, but you edited over an edit I had made to your question to add a `.catch()` to your example code (the 2nd code block in your question).  We should always be recommending answers that catch promise rejections.  Your answer currently does not show that.

Comment: On purpose yes, since getTopMeal like he implemented it, can't catch any errors, his code is eating up the error with catch and console.log -  so the added .catch you added doesn't catch anything. The answer he was looking for was adding a return. I explained that and then went on to talk on how he should not be eating up the errror but instead use an error handler.

Comment: In the future, when you reverse someone's edits, it would be appropriate to drop them a comment below the answer and explain what/why you changed instead.  Your current version is fine now.

Comment: Good point, sorry. Will keep that in mind in the future.